# replace null values by non-null values in same column based on values in another column

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following:

```
  |    A    |    B    |  
  |  blue   |  null   |
  |  orange |  null   | 
  |  orange |   x     | 
  |  blue   |   y     |
```

I would like to achieve this:

```
  |    A    |    B    |    C    |
  |  blue   |  null   |    y    |
  |  orange |  null   |    x    |
  |  orange |   x     |    x    |
  |  blue   |   y     |    y    |
```

The only values that orange can take in column B are null or x, same for blue (null or y)
Apologies if this has already been answered, I couldn't find it anywhere on the site.

Thanks

Comment: This could be a simple join, except that there are cases you didn't show or mention.  What if _orange_ has another row `'orange', 'z'` ?  Which value 'x' or 'z' do you want to show in the `orange` row containing `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have analytic functions available, you may simply try:

```sql
SELECT A, B, MAX(B) OVER (PARTITION BY A) AS C
FROM yourTable;
```

We could also use an aggregation approach:

```sql
SELECT t1.A, t1.B, t2.MAX_B AS C
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT A, MAX(B) AS MAX_B
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY A
) t2
    ON t2.A = t1.A
```

Answer (score 0):

above answer would work. I added my solution:

```
SELECT c1.A, c1.B, c2.B
FROM colors c1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT A, B
 FROM colors 
 where B is NOT NULL) c2
ON c1.A =  c2.A
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to ask here because there is a similar situation. my code is as below. but my problem is that my query is still not finished after 15 hours since my file is quite large.
Maybe this is normal for SQL or I should optimize my query?

(3.541.265 rows - PostgreSQL)

```
UPDATE clean_table_v01 AS t1
SET start_station_name = (
    SELECT start_station_name
    FROM clean_table_v01 AS t2
    WHERE t1.start_station_id = t2.start_station_id
      AND start_station_name NOTNULL
    LIMIT 1)
WHERE start_station_name ISNULL;
```